# Substituting special symbols in batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to substitute angle brackets for commas in a variable.

I'm trying to use trick with `for /f` for this, but it works only for echoing that variable.

This code works:

```
@ECHO OFF
set GSoption=" <<  >> "
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ('set GSoption') do echo "%%b"
```

But this one doesn't:

```
@ECHO OFF

set GSoption=" <<  >> "
set "Newvar=, ,"

for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ('set GSoption') do call :check %%b

exit /b

:check

SET "_result=%%Newvar:,=%1%%"
echo|call set /p="%_result%">>log.txt
exit /b

goto :eof
```

It prints `unexpected <<`

I want to substitute those angle brackets for commas.
Is it even possible without delayedexpansion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does not fully define your intention, however the solution is to use delayed expansion.

Here's a quick example replacing all `<` and `>` characters with `,` characters.

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "GSoption= <<  >> "
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "_Result=!GSOption:>=,!"
(
    For %%G In ("!_Result:<=,!") Do (
        EndLocal
        Echo %%~G
    )
) 1>"log.txt"
```

If you don't want a trailing CRLF, then use `Set /P` instead:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "GSoption= <<  >> "
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "_Result=!GSOption:>=,!"
(
    For %%G In ("!_Result:<=,!") Do (
        EndLocal
        Set /P "=%%~G" 0<NUL
    )
) 1>"log.txt"
```

As you have not explained the purpose of your `for` loop, you could of course do it without that too:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "GSoption= <<  >> "
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "_Result=!GSOption:>=,!"
(Echo(!_Result:^<=,!) 1>"log.txt"
EndLocal
```

And once again without the CRLF

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "GSoption= <<  >> "
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "_Result=!GSOption:>=,!"
Set /P "=!_Result:<=,!" 0<NUL 1>"log.txt"
EndLocal
```